# Error occuring only on Sunday for general simple weektable

Tags: javascript, html-table, dayofweek, days

Im working on a general table that highlights the current day of the week.
It worked on all days except for Sunday, today. Its now broken and it returns the following error:

[image]

Apparently the code is not robust at all? Should there be a completely different way of writing this? PS. the if statement is to prevent the code from firing for all the pages that do not contain such a worktable.

https://jsfiddle.net/mxopg6fz/

```js
workday();

function workday(){
    if (document.getElementById("weekdagtabel") !== null){
        var d = new Date().getDay();
        document.getElementById("day-"+d).classList.add("today");
    }
}
```

```css
.today {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.open {
  background-color: green; 
}

.closed {
  background-color: red; 
}



table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: .5em 0;
}

th, td {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

tr:hover {background-color: #EEE}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id="weekdagtabel">
        <tr id="day-1">
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td>08:00 - 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-2">
            <td>Tuesday</td>
            <td>08:00 - 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-3">
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>08:00 - 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-4">
            <td>Thursday</td>
            <td>08:00 - 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-5">
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>08:00 - 20:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-6">
            <td>Saturday</td>
            <td>Closed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="day-7">
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td>Closed</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `var d = new Date().getDay();` returns **0** means you're trying to access element `document.getElementById("day-0")` which does not exists

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yours and the answer given fixed the issue! Wish you a great Sunday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line of code:

```js
var d = new Date().getDay();
```

`d` variable [gets values](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_getday.htm) from `0` to `6` (`0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday, etc)

but you have ids from `1` to `7` in your html (`day-1` ... `day-7`)

For Sunday, your code is looking for id `day-0` here:

```js
document.getElementById("day-"+d)
```

but it is not present in your html, you have `day-7` instead

Use `day-0` id for Sunday instead of `day-7`, or adjust your `d` variable in your code, to reflect existing ids in your html file.

Comment: Thank you! Very very clear and I understand now why the outcome (0) did not correspond to any of the existing day-X numbers. Changing the last day-7 >> day-0 as id fixed the issue. I wish you a great Sunday :)